# Memory Leak Cant Solve it C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, free

i got a memory leak in my code because of malloc. But im little bit confused because of pointers and structs. Can someone tell me where i should use my free properly? This function gives me a bool Value if the Programm im looking for is running or not.

```
   typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD
    {
        ULONG NextEntryOffset;
        ULONG NumberOfThreads;
        LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi1;
        LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi2;
        LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi3;
        LARGE_INTEGER CreateTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
        UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
        KPRIORITY BasePriority;
        HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
        ULONG InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        ULONG HandleCount;
        BYTE Reserved4[4];
        PVOID Reserved5[11];
        SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
        SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
        LARGE_INTEGER Reserved6[6];
    }
    SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD;
    typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)(IN SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,
        IN OUT PVOID SystemInformation, IN ULONG SystemInformationLength, OUT OPTIONAL  PULONG ReturnLength);


    BOOLEAN IsProcessRunning(TCHAR* exe_name)
    {
        size_t bufferSize = 10000;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)malloc(bufferSize);

        ULONG ReturnLength;
        PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION pfnNtQuerySystemInformation = (PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
        NTSTATUS status;
        TCHAR* name;
        while (TRUE)
        {
            status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, (PVOID)pspid, bufferSize, &ReturnLength);
            if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                break;
            else if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {               
                return 1;   // error
            }
            bufferSize *= 2;
            pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)realloc((PVOID)pspid, bufferSize);
        }

        for (;; pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)(pspid->NextEntryOffset + (PBYTE)pspid))
        {
            name = (pspid->ImageName.Length && pspid->ImageName.Buffer) ? pspid->ImageName.Buffer : L"";
            //_tprintf(_T("P-Id: %d, P-Name: %ls\n"), pspid->UniqueProcessId, name);
            int result = wcscmp(exe_name, name);
            if (result == 0)
            {

                return TRUE;
            }
            if (npspid->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: If you use `C++11` then you can use a better case, That is Smart Pointers, no memory leak ever. (std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr) in <memory> header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `free` in your function, to release the memory you allocated with `malloc` (and re-allocated with `realloc`).

The problem is that you have several exit points in your function, so you should pay attention to release memory at each exit point.

In C, this is usually solved with a `goto` statement to a common exit point, where you do all the resource clean up.

However, in C++ you can do better. For example, you can use a *smart* pointer like `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique< BYTE[] >(bufferSize);
```

When the smart pointer instance goes out of scope (e.g. when function returns), the allocated memory is *automatically* released.

You can get a raw pointer to the allocated buffer using the `unique_ptr::get` method.

An alternative is using `std::vector<BYTE>` and its `resize` method.
If you want to get a pointer to the first element in the vector buffer (elements are stored contiguously), you can use the `vector::data` method. `vector::size` will return the number of items in the vector. And, again, the memory in the vector is *automatically* released.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the Windows API incorrectly: The API is designed so you could:

- Call it the first time with an empty buffer and retrieve the exact buffer size required
- Allocate the buffer
- Call it again and get the information

Like this:

```
BOOLEAN IsProcessRunning(TCHAR* exe_name)
{
    ULONG bufferSize;
    status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, nullptr, 0, &bufferSize);
    if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)malloc(bufferSize);

    ULONG bufferSize;
    status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, (PVOID)pspid, bufferSize, nullptr);
    if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (..)
    {
        [..]
    }
}
```

Next, after finishing to use the buffer in your `for` loop, you could simply free the memory using:

```
free(pspid);
```

**Better implementation**

An even better implementation will use smart pointers. The only things you have to change are the allocation of your `pspid`:

```
auto pspid = std::make_unique<BYTE[]>(bufferSize);
```

And the way you reference it: `pspid.get()`

And the memory will be freed automagically :)

Comment: ULONG bufferSize=100;// i have to initialize it
while (TRUE){status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, nullptr, 0, &bufferSize);
  if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
  {
   return 1;
  }
  bufferSize *= 2;
  pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)malloc( bufferSize);
 }
for (;; pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)(pspid->NextEntryOffset + (PBYTE)pspid))
 {...
  int result = wcscmp(exe_name, name);
  if (result == 0)
  {
   free(pspid);
   return TRUE;
  }
  if (pspid->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
 }
 free(pspid);
 return FALSE;

Comment: looks still wrong cause the function begins  now with 1gb ram and dont check the running process. Can you maybe help me? (Sry i dont know how to formate Text in a comment)

Comment: @PatrickHißler, no need for the `while` loop! Just do this directly in your method, see my updated answer.

Comment: Okay the memory leak still exist but exactly the same as the 1.st Version. And the function now always return true even when the process is not running

Answer (score 0):

You can just free the allocated block before each 'return' statement.

```
free(pspid);
return ...;
```

By the way:

> return 1;   // error

As you want to return a bool value, you should either return TRUE or FALSE and nothing else.